# How to make regex stop at a specific character

Tags: regex

I created this simple regular expression to match the "display:{value}" in a style attribute so that I can change it. It works fine as long as no text follows it.

```
(display:.*)[^;]
```

matches "display:block" when
comparing **display:block;**

But also matches "display:inline;color:red"
when comparing this **display:inline;color:red;**

How do I make it stop after it has found display:{value}

Comment: Make it non-greedy so that ti will not traverse any more than it needs to to return a match.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try in this way:

```
 (display:[^;]*)
```

Answer (score 0):

A non greedy regex that would stop at the first semi colon would look like this

```
(display:.*?);
```